# Connect springboot application to cloud SQL

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

```
db.driverName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

db.instanceName=<PROJECT_ID>:<REGION_ID>:<INSTANCE_ID>
db.url=jdbc:mysql:///some_db
db.username=xxxxx
db.password=xxxxx
db.maxPoolSize=50
db.minIdle=5
db.connTimeout=10000
db.idleTimeout=600000
db.maxLifetime=1800000
```

**My question is that can I use private IP of a particular instance to connect my service to cloudSQL. without using Instance Name.**

Please answer this, thanks in advance

I tried using private IP address in place of instance name but it did'nt work out

Comment: Yes, you can use the private IP directly, but you have to be connected to your private network to be able to reach your IP

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere understand that what I want to now how will I achieve this.
I mwan what changes should I made to this current properties file

Comment: Do this as any SQL database: forgive the instanceName (it won't be used) and format your db.url connection string like that `jdbc:mysql://<INSTANCE_HOST>:<DB_PORT>/<DB_NAME>`